# Dictionary object won't predicate

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a json object coming in as

```
{
"c_id": "261",
"customer_id": "178729",
"name": "Three, Test"
},
{
"c_id": "261",
"customer_id": "178727",
"name": "Two, Test"
},
{
"c_id": "261",
"customer_id": "178728",
"name": "Two, Test"
},
{
"c_id": "261",
"customer_id": "185186",
"name": "Valid, Another"
},
{
"c_id": "261",
"customer_id": "183889",
"name": "White, Betty"
}
```

However when this code processes

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *tempCustomers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [json objectForKey:@"data"]) {
            NSLog(@"dict: %@", dict);
            NSLog(@"name: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
            [tempCustomers addObject:dict];
        }

        self.customers = tempCustomers;
        NSLog(@"Customers: %@",customers);
        self.customerData = [self partitionObjects:[self customers] collationStringSelector:@selector(self)];
        NSLog(@"CustomerData: %@",customerData);

-(NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++) {
        [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    for (id object in array) {
        NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:[object objectForKey:@"name"] collationStringSelector:selector];
        [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
    }

    NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];


    for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections) {
        NSArray *sortedArray = [section sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        //NSLog(@"Sort: %@",sortedArray);
        //[sections addObject:[collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:selector]];
        [sections addObject:sortedArray];
    }

    return sections;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    NSLog(@"Search Display Controller: %@", self.customerData);
    //NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] '%@'",searchString];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] '%@'",searchString];
    self.filteredCustomers = [[self.customerData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Filtered Customers %@", self.filteredCustomers);

    return YES;
}
```

It shows

```
2012-03-26 14:15:21.885 MyApp[65799:15003] name: Two, Test
2012-03-26 14:15:21.885 MyApp[65799:15003] dict: {
    "c_id" = 261;
    "customer_id" = 178728;
    name = "Two, Test";
}
2012-03-26 14:15:21.885 MyApp[65799:15003] name: Two, Test
2012-03-26 14:15:21.885 MyApp[65799:15003] dict: {
    "c_id" = 261;
    "customer_id" = 185186;
    name = "Valid, Another";
}
2012-03-26 14:15:21.885 MyApp[65799:15003] name: Valid, Another
2012-03-26 14:15:21.886 MyApp[65799:15003] dict: {
    "c_id" = 261;
    "customer_id" = 183889;
    name = "White, Betty";
}
2012-03-26 14:15:21.886 MyApp[65799:15003] name: White, Betty
2012-03-27 08:35:24.764 MyApp[67330:fb03] Search Display Controller: (
        (
    ),
    (
                {
            "c_id" = 261;
            "customer_id" = 178664;
            name = "Test, My";
        },
                {
            "c_id" = 261;
            "customer_id" = 185182;
            name = "Test, valid";
        },
                {
            "c_id" = 261;
            "customer_id" = 178729;
            name = "Three, Test";
        },
                {
            "c_id" = 261;
            "customer_id" = 178727;
            name = "Two, Test";
        },
                {
            "c_id" = 261;
            "customer_id" = 178728;
            name = "Two, Test";
        }
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
                {
            "c_id" = 261;
            "customer_id" = 185186;
            name = "Valid, Another";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            "c_id" = 261;
            "customer_id" = 183889;
            name = "White, Betty";
        }
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    ),
        (
    )
)
2012-03-27 08:35:24.766 MyApp[67330:fb03] Filtered Customers (
)
```

Notice the " " around the name key are missing. I believe this is why my `NSPredicate` in my `searchDisplayController` isn't working. Why are the quotes being removed and how would I fix my `searchDisplayController` to work?

Comment: Is this all of the log statements?  I don't see the one from the searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString: method? It appears that this method isn't being called.  Have you set the delegate for the search controller?  I'm not sure you should worry about the missing quotes, at least in OS X, the log statements seem to randomly leave them off.

Comment: @rdelmar I added the additional logs. Of course I truncated them to match the other sections. You will see empty arrays which are for the collation sections that don't have any customers in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed, in your predicate, you have single quotes around the %@ -- they shouldn't be there.  Putting the single quotes around %@ turns it into a literal.